# What is the best approach to implement a (static-html) blog to a react web app?

Tags: reactjs, blogs, gatsby, static-html

I'm currently developing a web app based on React. The web app is a SPA where you can navigate through different sections.

Now I want to implement a blog to my SPA as an additional section. I'm not sure what is the best approach here. I guess in terms of SEO it doesn't make sense to render the blog in the browser at the client site (with React).

Therefore my idea is to have some kind of static websites for the blog, maybe based on Netifly CMS and Gatsby and then to inject this static sites to my SPA as a section in my navigation bar.

Does this make sense at all? Or what would be a better approach?

For a better understanding here is a schmeatic representation of the website
https://ibb.co/71mrsqJ